# How to make an obstacle hit a wall not go through the wall/obstacle for Javascript,Html,CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code and I already my main block moving when the WASD keys are clicked but now I wanted my block to do a simple hit detection when it touches the black square box how will I go with that
the code  --> https://codepen.io/jsmirga22/pen/QWGZmzG   any answers on how to make my block move into the square box detect the other box running into it would help alot

```
  `// left 37 right 39 down 40 up 38
```

```js
// left 37 right 39 down 40 up 38
// D 68 S 83 A 65 W 87
// pi var is actually guyleft
var obstacle1 = document.getElementById('obstacle1');
var guy = document.getElementById('guy')
var con = document.getElementById('con')

var pi = 0
var guytop = 0
var joe = window.getComputedStyle(guy)
function test(){
  var joe = window.getComputedStyle(guy)
 guy.textContent = joe.getPropertyValue('right')
  console.log(guy.textContent)
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
console.log(ctx);
}
function sa(e) {
 
 
   if(e.keyCode === 68){
      pi += 12
     guy.style.left = pi + 'px'
       if(pi >= 3165) {
      pi -= 12
     }
     if(pi >= 540) {
       window.scrollBy(12, 0)
     }
     
   }
   if(e.keyCode === 65){
      pi -= 12
     guy.style.left = pi + 'px'
     if(pi >= -540){
              window.scrollBy(-12, 0)
     }
     
   }
  if(e.keyCode === 83){
      guytop += 12
     guy.style.top = guytop + 'px'
    if(guytop >= 770){
      guytop -= 12
  
    }
     
   }
   if(e.keyCode === 87){
      guytop -= 12
     guy.style.top = guytop + 'px'
     
   }
}

document.onkeydown = sa
```

```css
#con{
height: 1000px;
width: 2500px;
outline: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
}

#guy{
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
 
}

#obstacle1{
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 120px;
  left: 120px;
  right: 120px;
  
}
.b{
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <canvas id="canvas" class="b" style="background: #000"></canvas>
  <body>
    <div id="con">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/cjiUr93zFLG2ijslHBOh5wBa9FNhHYIsTSSVu_lsv2pVkv6tX8TYMmTQBshaMVmuHipfsXVyIY2WrQ8vKTauD9xb6Bc-gGISECUkRlnxLnhnGoEBNN9VzW7WA_kyR6W7Psknqf9pYDDRPl8nRmtck02Ljy9E3zhhXHdfPBF_3KjhxrD4X6jm57L6vd98dIAs0nDe80Pue06FJAuqSY1T6r-j1T1nFnuo2753XYJEYZc_tjnnvnNsQEBSGQRmKAYtSPiAWXFyCc62Q6fKRdzHR5esGhxo01fGggtbGU8v_AKr24l-CE5bR-2RRI1R_w_SKQSBiQs4Td6Fk7vFfPQK0wX3NvVVqlHxQ6ZMBFs9acEHNd_i8q99CFKJqDXux01xBnUFi4lMpyyewufxHZJTevcJLNTu26M-RmTTOf_91By1gbppW_AnR-OGH6GUxVXGi0YdEAJoO-O8QOTWsymX_IClQUXX8XJUyHk8udEzzCunXRfKkF6GTv9-xeFLZJ-PKbSYCtHPh1oErnkaF1QA6tIweSyHOfbRZF4TlvC37rZ85ZWPXIjTA73LQFlHJC7NetpAoDFjT7zMHu3mjmSjaEK-_xFT3NNh9QnAP-aGW7762Y1X8PKCHbP0JqiB0H2ej3P6ZesN0tyrGtlm1aoKOfo5-NJmPv735cwA02avk6NAb1vvJFyLkcKv1JjAZ56H5u2Z3r6ygWdj3XublxdI7YlH=w64-h83-no?authuser=0" <div id="guy">></div>
      <div id="obstacle1" onclick="test()"></div>
      <div id="obstacle2"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
```

Comment: **Not the solution**: Use this image for the guy `https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSV25.png`... Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/RwKWrmz

Comment: It seems that you can get the size and position value of the obstacle, and check the position value of 'guy' every time the 'onkeydown' event is activated, and return hit event if they overlap.

Comment: you have a code example of what you're talking about?